# Is it possible to disable sudo timeout in the current shell?

Tags: linux, sudo

Certain applications (for example [yay](https://github.com/Jguer/yay)) uses sudo to run some commands as root. This means that I have to sit in front of the terminal and wait until I'm prompted by sudo for a password, then enter it manually to make yay continue. I can avoid this by running a command as sudo first (like `sudo -v`). That way yay can run commands as sudo without it prompting me for a password.

But some times, applications take so long to install that the sudo session times out (15 minutes) and sudo re-prompts me for a password. Since I usually leave my computer or switch to a different workspace while this happens, the sudo password prompt usually times out which is super annoying.

I don't want to disable the sudo timeout altogether, since it's there for a reason. However, when I expect that a command that uses sudo will take a *long* time, I would like to be able to disable sudo timing out for the current shell only.

Something like:

```
sudo --disable-timeout
```

Now I should be able to run sudo in the current shell, without ever having to re-enter my password, or until I run `sudo -k`.

Is something like this possible, or will I have to write a wrapper script that regularly refreshes the sudo session for me?

Comment: Add the specific command that you need to run to /etc/sudoers so that you don't need the password.

Comment: @stark There isn't a specific command. `yay` uses sudo under the hood, I don't even know which commands it runs, and it probably runs a bunch of different commands.

Comment: By **refreshing** credentials in the background:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/634701/223253

Answer (score 8):

Here is one possible workaround. Write a script like this (e.g. `sudo-stay-validated.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    sudo -v
    sleep 60
done
```

Run the script in the terminal where sudo should stay validated:

```
$ bash sudo-stay-validated.sh
```

Press Ctrl+Z to place it in the background, then remember to run `$ bg` to resume the script in the background.

This keeps sudo validated in the current shell until it's closed.

Comment: An equivalent to Ctrl+Z + `bg` is `./sudo-stay-validated.sh &` — the ampersand makes it launch in background from the start, and you can later use `fg` to "foreground" it as usual.

Comment: @ulidtko You won't be able to input the password though.

Comment: Right... `sudo -v && ./sudo-stay-validated.sh &` then :)

Comment: Yes indeed. I do that sometimes.

Comment: Shorter: `sudo -v && while sleep 60 && sudo -v; do true; done &`

Answer (score 8):

There seems no easy way to do this for the *current shell* but you can set a timeout globally.

In order to set a different timeout (globally) than the default (=15 min) you can edit `/etc/sudoers`:

```sh
sudo visudo                                       # opens /etc/sudoers for editing
# change the following line:
# Defaults    env_reset
# to:
Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=30    # timeout in minutes
```

Or:

```sh
cd /etc/sudoers.d
sudo visudo -f username
Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=30    # timeout in minutes
```

Special values:

- `-1`: no timeout
- `0`: get prompted every single time

Answer (score 7):

Generally, the sudo timeout is there for a (security) reason. When you (successfully) try to circumvent that timeout, you weaken the security of your system. So, lets have another look on the stated problem: you run a lengthy job, after some time sudo asks for a password and times out. You propose preventing sudo from asking for the password. Alternatively, prevent sudo from timing out. Put:

```
Defaults passwd_timeout=0
```

into your `sudoers` file to let sudo wait until you enter your password. This will prevent your timeout problem but will stall your build until you enter the password. On the plus side, you avoid compromising security.

Alternatively, since you mention yay specifically, there is a command line option for yay which makes it call sudo in the background to prevent it from timing out. From `man sway`:

```
--sudoloop
    Loop sudo calls in the background to prevent sudo from timing out during long builds.
```

Comment: Huh, that basically renders my script obsolete. I wonder if this is a new command line option, since I've never seen it before :/

Answer (score -4):

Well, why not to use **screen** for this purpose? Connect with **ssh**, start **screen**, start your **command** and **de-attach** from **screen**. Then when you ready to check if it your *procedure* completed then attach again. But even better send an email notification to special *email* address and your phone will notify you that the **job** is done (I hope that you have more or less modern cell phone). https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen

Comment: I don't understand what this solves. Sudo will still time out in the bash session in screen, meaning that the command I've run will freeze waiting for the sudo password prompt, then time out and exit.

Comment: Well, you did not provide enough information to understand the task you try to accomplish. You can extend timeout (visudo) when you know in advance how long it can take. The process as rule runs under other user -- you could add cron job to run let say each 2-5 minute and check for _marker_ file and initiate desired script. On your part you put your data in proper location, then **touch marker file** and cron job will do the rest. Sudo intended to give temporary access to run a command -- it is not intended to run unattended for extended period of time.

Comment: For clarifiation: cron job is run by user you sudo in.

Comment: From your post it is not clear when you invoke the sudo -- before you start a job, or in middle of the job script starts sudo and you need provide the password. In last case you need look into **expect**. https://itbook.store/books/9781565920903

Comment: I have updated by question to try to make it more clear. I don't run sudo myself, the application `yay` runs sudo to perform some commands as root. I have to wait patiently until `yay` tries to run sudo, since it will prompt me for a password. I enter the password, and `yay` continues. If `yay` is super slow (compiling webkit, for example) then sudo will time out and it will prompt me for a password again when it tries to run sudo. This is super annoying since I'm very often away from the PC when this happens, or focused on a different workspace.

Comment: Ok, now more details about process is available. What exactly sudo does as root? Compilation can be done in most cases without root privileges at all. But it is unavoidable to run installation (of programs,libraries) as root in system bin/lib location.

Comment: `yay` is a tool for downloading, compiling, packaging and installing applications using configurations from the Arch User Repository (AUR). It needs root access to install dependencies and to install the completed packages.

Comment: Ok, now it looks like you are talking about Arch Linux. Are you package maintainer? Download,compiling,packaging is not require **root** privileges unless you stumble on dependencies (is there a way to find and pre-install dependencies in advance?). The installation of packages indeed will require **root** level access. Did you visit next webpage? https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/yay/ I believe that your question should be directed there and probably somebody will answer it.

Comment: I have played with Arch Linux (manually install Arch, add required packages, install/configure GUI, install most common programs). I understand that if you package maintainer or you build your own distribution based on Arch you have to compile a lot of packages which would take a lot of time -- and with **sudo** you could run into this issue. But then why not just run the `yay` under root account? You could do it on one `development`/`maintenance` computer -- all other computer systems could download pre-compiled packages from repository over ftp/http.

Comment: NOTE: You should provide sufficient information in your question to get useful answer. Something like following: I am a package maintainer for Arch Linux, I utilize `yay` utility to download,compile,package,install software. `yay` utility runs for prolonged period of time, during it's work it runs **sudo** utility which timeout if I do not enter password (I perform some other work in parallel). Is there a way to resolve this issue so that **sudo** does not  timeout?

Comment: I am not sure if following solution will be acceptable for your situation: open terminal, ssh root@localhost, start `yay`, let it run -- no sudo = no timeout.

Comment: Of if you do it remotely: open terminal, ssh user@computer, start _screen_, ssh root@localhost, start `yay`, de-attach from screen. As the time passes by: open terminal, ssh user@computer, attach to _screen_, see the progress, de-attach from screen. As the time passes by: open terminal, ssh user@computer, attach _screen_, `yay` finished, exit [ssh root@localhost], exit _screen_, exit ssh user@remote.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not a package maintainer. I just have a lot of packages installed from the AUR (through yay). Often when I run `yay -Syyu` to update my packages, it can take an hour or more to complete, prompting me for the sudo password multiple times during that time. I don't consider running yay as root to be an acceptable workaround, for security reasons.